# "Error loading RadChart Image" on IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, telerik, asp.net-4.0, radchart

I'm using a Telerik RadChart control on my ASP.NET web application.

This works fine when running on localhost, but now the application has been deployed to IIS7 and the following error appears:

[image]

Why is this? And how can I resolve the issue?

I've seen on some forum posts that the solution is to add the following into `<system.webServer>` in the web.config:

`<add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>`

However, I have already done this, and the error is still appearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, for IIS7 the Telerik HTTP Handlers that you have in <system.web> <httphandlers> need to be in <system.webServer><handlers>

I'm not sure if you should remove from system.web but just copy over your telerik http handler
for rad chart, should look something like this:

```
<add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2011.3.1305.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false" />
```

Comment: Cheers Brian, but I already have the following in `<system.webServer>`: `<add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>`. So I don't think this is the cause of the issue. Can you think of any other reasons? Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

in web.config file... add the following:-

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ChartImage.axd_*" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx_*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd_*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

that solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what they're doing with the `RadChart` and the `ChartHttpHandler`, but I solved my issue by changing the `requireSSL` attribute of the `system.web > httpCookies` section to false:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" lockItem="true" />
 </system.web>
```

We'd recently just migrated our application (which used SSL and worked fine with RadControls) to a new server and were running with no SSL certificate temporarily.

I'd followed all previous instructions to solve this issue including setting all `RadChart` `EnableHandlerDetection` properties to false while using handlers placed **only** in the `system.webServer > handlers` section and removing any in the `system.web > httpHandlers` section, with no luck. I was either getting the error posted by the OP or the message telling you to add a handler in the (old) `system.web > httpHandlers` section -- no permutation of these settings helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue despite already having the entries in `<system.web> <httphandlers>` (for IIS6) and `<system.webServer><handlers>` (for IIS7). The difference for me was a project that is a mix of ASP.NET WebForms and MVC.
The fix was adding this line in Global.asax. Now any charts in aspx pages under Reports/ folder works.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Reports/ChartImage.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for IIS7 the Telerik HTTP Handlers that you have in

I solved the issue by adding ChartHttpHandler

```
<handlers>
      <add name="ChartHandler" path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" />
</handlers>
 <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

and also i added

```
<rad:RadChart UseSession="false">
```